# Exploratory factor analysis using individual variables

Tags: factor-analysis

Firstly I am a beginner in analysis. I conducted a survey, and while running EFA (SPSS), five dimensions were reduced to 3. And I can't find any logical connection between them, and then I again performed EFA of 5 dimensions individually. Then I got it correctly. So I just want to know is it possible to show the results of EFA like this. Please provide me some references.

Comment: Can you edit that to explain in more detail just exactly what you did? I cannot understand how the second time you got a different result from the first.

Comment: Sir, I conducted a survey by using a questionnaire which includes 5 different variables and 22 scale items the same. But when I performed EFA the the scale items were distributed under 3 dimensions instead of 5, but I cant establish a logical connection between them. So I performed it separately means, conducted EFA by selecting scale items only related concerned variable, at that time I got it correctly. So I want to know is it possible to show the results like this, I need some reference please help...

Comment: If I understand you correctly that seems to me to be incorrect and I would report the first analysis.